# How to stop looping thread

Tags: c++, qt, qthread

I want to stop a looping thread when a signal was emitted so here is my code

```
void  MyThread::stopWatchingThread()
{
    qDebug()<<"MyThread::stopWatchingThread()";    
    Keep_running=false;
    qDebug()<<"MyThread::stopWatchingThread Keep_running"<<Keep_running;
    ...
}

void MyThread::run()
{
  qDebug()<<"MyThread::run()";
  qDebug()<<"MyThread::run Keep_running"<<Keep_running;  
  while(Keep_running)
    {
     ...
     }
  qDebug()<<"MyThread::run Keep_running"<<Keep_running;
  Keep_running=false;
  qDebug()<<"MyThread::run Keep_running"<<Keep_running;
}

void Watcher::Init()
{
    WatchingThread=new MyThread(this->L_RootToWatch);
    connect(this,SIGNAL(stopmonotiring()),WatchingThread, SLOT(stopWatchingThread()));
...
}
void Watcher::StartWatching()
{
    WatchingThread->start();
}

void Watcher::StopWatching()
{
    emit stopmonotiring();        
}
```

So every thing goes all right  but my problem is  that `Keep_running` never get `false` value in `MyThread::run()` after emitting `stopWatchingThread` and so `while` loop for ever.
What did I miss ?
any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked if you actually enter into `MyThread::stopWatchingThread()`?

Comment: Yes and my `Keep_running` was false

Comment: Are you sure that Keep_Running is the same variable? Print its address (use `qDebug() << &Keep_Running;`) both from `run()` and from `MyThread::stopWatchingThread()` and compare

Comment: Also, did you check, that you are actually iterating over your while loop? As in: it is not hanging in the first iteration waiting for some event, e.g. network IO, that never occurs.

Comment: My while loop tests only `Keep_running` and it is not waiting for any event,@satuon yes it is the same variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't create threaded classes explicitly in Qt.  Instead, create a worker object, move that object to a `QThread`, then call `start()` on the `QThread`.  Here's a quick example:

```
class Worker : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  Worker( QObject * parent = 0 )
    : QObject( parent )
  {}

public slots:
  void doWork( ... )
  { 
    // do work here
  }

  void stopMonitoring()
  { 
    emit finished();
  }

signals:
  void finished();
};

int main()
{
  Worker * w = new Worker();
  QThread * thread = new QThread();
  QObject::connect( w, SIGNAL(finished()), thread, SLOT(quit())
  QObject::connect( w, SIGNAL(finished()), w, SLOT(deleteLater())
  QObject::connect( thread, SIGNAL(finished()), thread, SLOT(deleteLater())
  w->moveToThread( thread );
  thread->start();

  // some other object emits a signal connected to the 'doWork()' slot.
}
```

I omitted some of the standard QApplication boiler-plate, but you have that already if you're using Qt.  This should get you started.

Answer (score 1):

As your run() method is blocking and the event loop never entered, the slot stopWatchingThread will never be called. You must call exec() and not block the event loop by a spinning loop in run(). Either that, or have the watcher thread call stopWatchingThread directly instead of using a signal/slot connection. I'd go for the latter. keepRunning will be accessed from multiple threads then, so you have to protect it using a QMutex, QReadWriteLock or QAtomic. (Start with QMutex, it's easiest).

Answer (score 0):

If you use an event loop in your thread just post the `quit()` signal to the thread object.

Comment: thank you for your response, What did you mean by event loop?  is it the while block? I called `quit()` in `stopWatchingThread()` after setting `Keep_running` but in vain no effect.

Comment: You start the event loop by calling `QThread::exec()` from your `run()` method. See http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qthread.html#exec

Comment: An infinite/long running while loop will render the event loop useless.

Comment: Of course, but I didn't say from inside his while loop. He should just remove this while loop, call `exec()`, and use a timer with zero interval to do his processing.

Comment: I need to maintain the while loop (so I can handle the event of file creation inside of a watched directory : using inotify ...),I tried to call stopWatchingThread from Watcher without signal/slot and protect Keep_running with a QMutex but in vain MyThread still running even after destruction and I get `QThread: Destroyed while thread is still running`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your C++ compiler optimizes away the read operation on `Keep_running`. Try declaring it as `volatile`, which tells the compiler that this variable might change "unexpectedly", e.g. from other threads or hardware interrupts.

Comment: Thank you for your time, I change it to `volatile`, same result :(